# The same question within hours, by three different users. Someone’s exam?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation, exams

Today, at least three times essentially the same question about ideals in a polynomial ring $R[x]$ has been asked by three different users (first instance is the initial steps); same notation, even.

1. [First instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941420/should-i-use-induction-in-this-proof).
2. [Second instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942255/an-inductive-proof-regarding-ideals).
3. [Third instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3942268/how-to-conclude-that-px-is-in-i).

This seems too much of a coincidence. Could this be someone’s exam? Are the three accounts from a similar geographic region?

---

Third instance was deleted by the author about 15 minutes after I posted this question. If you have high enough reputation it should be visible.

---

One of the users [has admitted](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8129433?noredirect=1) that this is part of “an assignment”.

Comment: From the writing style, it seems very likely the first and third are the same person.

Comment: @EricWofsey: In which case, moderators should step in... presumably they can look at IP addresses, etc.

Comment: Just to make it clear: if your reputation is over 10 000, you will be able to view the deleted posts.

Comment: Arturo, same here: [First instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3927531/471884), [Second instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926235/471884), [Third instance](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3916297/471884). I just found out about the third one using the MathSE search. Have flagged.

Comment: I've just shared this thread with all the math faculty at my school. I would suggest that anyone who spots other suspicious questions leave links here, so we can have one page to point faculty to.

Comment: In case the professor from the first question shows up here, they should be aware that it is asked and answered on Chegg https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/3-10-points-let-r-commutative-ring-let-r-x-r-1--given-ideal-cr-x-k-e-n-let-lk-cr-consist-0-q63380014

Comment: FYI, the comment that admitted about part of an assignment has been deleted (but mods can still see it)

Comment: My "favourite" example of this occurred a few years ago. The  question body consisted of a low quality phone photo of the question on the exam paper, including the OP's name written at the top of the page, with virtually no accompanying text, apart from a plea for help, ASAP. :rolls eyes:

Comment: Thanks mods for handling both situations.

Comment: One time in grad school, someone posted a final exam problem on MSE. I found it while searching for some information to help better my understanding. I almost wrote, "nice try, fellow MATH 777 (or whatever) student" but decided against it. Professor found out and boy was it awkward. Everyone got interviewed about it...

Comment: I believe there should be an option for which a user or the OP can delete their answer/question after getting approval from moderators for a valid justification.

Comment: @GAUSS1860, users *can* delete their questions and answers with no approval needed (although I think that deleting questions can only be done before people answer).

Comment: I am aware of that, I gave my opinion that this should happen if and only if the moderator accepts that. Furthermore, I believe that after the exam, the professor should interview each student and those who cheated will definitely be caught